# fatal error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, moveit

Hello I am following a tutorial from Mastering_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming

this is my `test_random.cpp` file

```
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_interface_demo", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
  // start a ROS spinning thread
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  // this connecs to a running instance of the move_group node
  move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
  // specify that our target will be a random one
  group.setRandomTarget();
  // plan the motion and then move the group to the sampled target 
  group.move();
  ros::waitForShutdown();
}
```

when I run `catkin_make` I get the following error

```
fatal error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/home/murtaza/catkin_ws/src/seven_dof_arm_test/src/add_collision_objct.cpp:1:10: fatal error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/add_collision_objct.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/add_collision_objct.dir/src/add_collision_objct.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/add_collision_objct.dir/src/add_collision_objct.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10094: recipe for target 'seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/add_collision_objct.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/add_collision_objct.dir/all] Error 2
seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/remove_collision_objct.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/remove_collision_objct.dir/src/remove_collision_objct.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/remove_collision_objct.dir/src/remove_collision_objct.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10131: recipe for target 'seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/remove_collision_objct.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/remove_collision_objct.dir/all] Error 2
[ 23%] Linking CXX executable /home/murtaza/catkin_ws/devel/lib/seven_dof_arm_test/check_collision
[ 23%] Built target check_collision
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(seven_dof_arm_test)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cmake_modules
  interactive_markers
  moveit_core
  moveit_ros_perception
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
  pluginlib
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

###############################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES seven_dof_arm_test
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS cmake_modules interactive_markers moveit_core moveit_ros_perception moveit_ros_planning_interface pluginlib roscpp std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(test_random_node src/test_random.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(test_random_node seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(test_random_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(test_custom_node src/test_custom.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(test_custom_node seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(test_custom_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )




## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(find_ee_coordinate src/find_ee_coordinate.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(find_ee_coordinate seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(find_ee_coordinate
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )


## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(add_collision_objct src/add_collision_objct.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(add_collision_objct seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(add_collision_objct
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )



## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(remove_collision_objct src/remove_collision_objct.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(remove_collision_objct seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(remove_collision_objct
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )





## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(move_group_plan_group_state src/move_group_plan_group_state.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(move_group_plan_group_state seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(move_group_plan_group_state
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )




## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(check_collision src/check_collision.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(check_collision seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(check_collision
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )


#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS seven_dof_arm_test seven_dof_arm_test_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_seven_dof_arm_test.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

when I run  `rosrun seven_dof_arm_test test_random_node`
 It shows me this error

```
[rospack] Error: package 'seven_dof_arm_test' not found
```

I am new to ROS therefore, I would be grateful if someone can explain to me my mistakes in detail

Comment: One small obvious thing is in the CMakeLists.txt: the catkin_package() ought to have the INCLUDE and CATKIN_DEPENDS lines uncommented. You don't have any system dependencies or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to download `seven_dof_arm_test` package in the `src` folder of your ROS workspace.

- Download this package in the `src` folder of your ROS workspace using `git clone https://github.com/jocacace/seven_dof_arm_test.git`.
- Compile the package by running `catkin_make` command.

You can also create the above package using below command:

```
catkin_create_pkg seven_dof_arm_test catkin cmake_modules interactive_markers moveit_core moveit_ros_perception moveit_ros_planning_interface pluginlib roscpp std_msgs
```